# Strange IPC messaging behaviour in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

My index.js file contains this line of code:

```
ipcRenderer.send("copy-file-to-local", (fpath, fname))
```

and my main.js file contains these lines of code:

```
ipcMain.on("copy-file-to-local", (_event, fpath, fname) => {
    // do things!
    console.log(fpath)
})
```

Outputting event always works correctly, outputting `fpath` returns `fname` and outputting `fname` returns undefined. This behaviour is observed regardless of whether I pass `event` in index.js. I've basically just stared at my console in confusion for the past ~2 hours. No matter how I change the arguments around, it always seems that  there's a limit to 2 arguments. What dark magic drives this issue? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the extra parentheses around the arguments, this turns them into an expression that evaluates to one value.

```
function f(arg1, arg2){
    console.log(arg1, arg2);
}

f((a, b)) //B, undefined
f(a, b)    //A, B
```

Comment: Well I'm an idiot, I think I misread an example somewhere and figured it was a tuple or something. Thank you so much!